# how to display value carried by ajax on view

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

i have add ajax on my dropdown. its work is that when we select a option from dropdown it shows a value related to selected option in alertbox . but now i want that value will display on my view page on which dropdown is displayed . i dont know how to do it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.expenses-dropdown').change(function () {
        var ledger_name = $("select.expenses-dropdown option:selected").val();
        var ledgerArray = ledger_name.split('-');
        ledgerid = ledgerArray[0];
        name = ledgerArray[1];
        //      alert ("The name of ledger you selected is "+name+".");
        $.ajax({
            url: <? php echo '\''.site_url('payment/ledger_budget').'/\''; ?> +name,
            success: function (data) {
                var ledger_bal = $.trim(data);;
                alert("the amount is " + ledger_bal + ".");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

i just want to know how to display that value carried by ajax.

Comment: `$(selector).text(newText)` ?

Comment: You have to create select box with response data?

Answer (score 0):

Add a span in your page like :

```
<span id="result"></span>
```

And in your ajax code :

```
var ledger_bal = $.trim(data);
$("#result").html(ledger_bal);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a div,span or anything like textbox and pass that value to that created element.

For example :
You create something like :

```
<div id="ledger_bal"></div>
```

in your ajax code assign value to your created element instead of alerting the value.

```
$('#ledger_bal').html(ledger_bal);
```

Hope this helps you understand.If you have any further queries feel free to ask.